# How to render polygons with an animated water texture via Cesium?

Tags: cesiumjs

I’m loading some geoJSON data and would like to symbolize the data with an animated water material. When I run this code below, all I see is a white polygon. Am I missing something? I have tried to utilize a simple color type fabric with the same result.

```
            viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
            var entities = dataSource.entities.values;
            for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
                var entity = entities[i];
                    entity.polygon.outline = false;
                    
                entity.polygon.material = new Cesium.Material({
                fabric: {
                  type: "Water",
                  uniforms: {
                    normalMap: "water.jpg",
                    frequency: 10000.0,
                    animationSpeed: 0.01,
                    amplitude: 1.0,
                  },
                },
              })

            }


    });
```